# How to show only files that are larger than 2000 on bash in one line?

Tags: bash

How to show only files that are larger than 2000 on bash in one line?

```
[gooder@GOD]$ find videos/ -type f -printf '%k %p\n' |sort -n |tail -n 20
1760 videos/0-2GBou1t.mp4
1500752 videos/0-2GBout.mp4
2291528 videos/0-2GB1.mkv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean 2000 bytes.

```
find videos/ -type f -size +2000c
```